# How can I change the name of database in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[how to change the name of database in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpKfx.png)

Can we change the name of a database in Cloud Firestore? I didn't give name to the database. I want to change the name of the database from
sample-51580 to sample. In the Firebase console, I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: This should correspond to the name of your project? Also, this is unrelated to Flutter, please remove the Flutter tag.

Comment: no you cannot, you might have to create a new firebase project

Answer (score 0):

The name you're showing in your screenshot if the project ID. There is no way to modify this ID once a project has been created. If you want a different project ID, you'll have to create a new project.

This *does* like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though, so you might want to think/explain what underlying problem you're trying to solve here.

Answer (score 0):

These days you don't have to start a new project. Just create a extra Firestore database in Google Cloud Console, see [this link at Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-databases?&_ga=2.49228773.-2146502246.1692180071#create_a_database) for more information.